# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, ios

I have a question about the memory management. In my app delegate, I have the following method; where `welcomeViewController` is an ivar.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    welcomeViewController = [[CBWelcomeViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *appNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeViewController];
    [self.window addSubview: [appNavigationController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

To release the memory for `welcomeViewController`, I simply call release on it in the dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [welcomeViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

My question is, what is the correct way to manage the memory of `appNavigationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `appNavigationController` an instance variable and `release` it in `dealloc`.

You do not need to have `welcomeViewController` as an instance variable, quite the opposite. 
Simply alloc/init it, then pass it off to the `UINavigationController`, which then retains it, then immediately `release` it.

Comment: So where should I release this? If I release it straight after `addSubview:' the UINavigationController doesn't load the subview. Also, when I addSubview:, this increases `appNavigationController's retain count to 2, then if I release it in dealloc, it is still 1 (ie unreleased). Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to release it within the dealloc method, like you're currently releasing the welcomeViewController.

(Incidentally, you should actually release the welcomeViewController straight after you've used it to init the navigation controller (i.e.: within your init method), as the navigation controller will retain it.)