# iOS Memory Management, UIWindow addSubview:, and tab controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

When using the following code, do you need to do anything to release the tab controller's view? While working on an app, I've analyzed the project and it reports that there is a potential link on the line using `addSubview:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [window addSubview:[tabController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**MyAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : AppDelegate {
    UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;

@end
```

**MyAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize tabController, window;

- (void)dealloc {
    [tabController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [window addSubview:[tabController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Do I need to release `tabController.view` before I release the `tabController`? Or inside the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421418/applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions-memory-management) seems to say that I just need to release the controller in dealloc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you should release the `tabController` at some point, but in reality it does not matter. The `window` exists for the life of the program, and when the program is terminated all memory is purged, so there will be no leaks for objects retained by the `window`.

This will raise an alert when you run Build/Build and Analyze, but it can safely be ignored. The same applies to a `navController` added at this level or any other retained subview of the main window.

Comment: Thanks. This 'fixes' the issue. Interesting now I'm starting to understand the Analyze message a bit better and found that it had to do with a UIImageView that is being added to `[tabController tabBar]` as a subview (for a background). But this is still very good to know and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

u have sythesized so call it with self

```
   - (void)dealloc {

      [self.tabController release];

      self.tabController=nil;

      [self.window release];

      self.window = nil;


   }
```

Comment: where is ur window in appdelegate

Comment: I've updated the question with how the UIWindow is tied in. Thanks!

Comment: i hope u connect the ib of window to window ivariable

Comment: Yes, `window` and `tabController` are connected via IB.